# Define a specific case for a templated function (C++)

Tags: c++, templates

So in my .h file I have

```
template <class T>
void getValue(T *val, int element, int index);
```

and then in my .cc file I have a function:

```
template <class T>
void RParser::getValue(T *val, int element, int index)
{
```

I also have it explicitly instantiated:

```
    template void RParser::getValue<char>(char *val, int element, std::string subrecName);
    template void RParser::getValue<long long>(long long *val, int element, std::string subrecName);
    template void RParser::getValue<float>(float *val, int element, std::string subrecName);
...
```

this works but I would like to make a whole different function for std::string

I tried:

```
template <class std::string>
void RParser::getValue<std::string>(std::string * val, int element, int index)
{
```

but that didn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Related to the two answers below:  you might read Herb Sutter's article, ["Why not Specialize Function Templates?"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: Thanks for all of the helpful replys, I just used Mike's syntax for specializing a template in order to fix up the problem.  I did realize that you could just overload the function but I assumed (maybe wrongly) that specializing the template was the more correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specialise the template, then the syntax is:

```
template<> 
void RParser::getValue<std::string>(std::string* val, int element, int index) {}
```

But as Neil's answer says, you don't need to specialise this function template; an overload will do the job:

```
void RParser::getValue(std::string* val, int element, int index) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a template at all - just an ordinary function:

```
void RParser::getValue(std::string * val, int element, int index)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply illegal C++ to specialize a template member function of a class. I think in C++00x this has been relaxed.*emphasized text*

EDIT:

```
class foo {
    template <typename T> T bar(const T & t){
        return t;
    }

    template <> int bar<int>(const int & t){ 
        return t + 1 ;
    }
};


int main(int c, const char * v[]){
    foo f;
}
```

when compiling

```
 % gcc /tmp/foo.cpp
/tmp/foo.cpp:6: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class foo’
/tmp/foo.cpp:6: error: template-id ‘bar<int>’ in declaration of primary template
```

Comment: I thought it was only illegal within templated classes?

Comment: _Partial_ specialization is illegal. @ jon hanson: That would be inside a _class template_, not inside a _class_. Different animals.

Comment: specialization of a member function is illegal inside a class or class template. See the edit above with gcc error output.